# android bluetooth pairing programmatically without confirmation

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, pairing

I am using Android SDK version 28 and a pixel 3. Is it possible to pair the device without user confirmation popup? Can I downgrade Android? Jailbreak install another OS?

Comment: What if I root the device ?